# Volkswagen passat won't start (with video)

Tags: starting, vw, passat

Can someone guess what the problem is?
Car is a 2006 Volkswagen Passat 2.0 TFSI

Here is a link to the video:
https://vimeo.com/231681553

Is the battery dead? What about the **EPC** light?

Car is parked on the roof of a multilevel parking lot.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's precisely the same behaviour as I see from my 2012 Golf (same VW CAN-BUS architecture) when it has a flat battery.

Your best option is to find someone in the car park with jump leads and get a jump from them.  If the car has a manual gearbox you potentially have the option of bump / roll starting it.  Other than that it's a case of either charge the battery (possible if you have a solar charger and an hour or two spare), use a "jump pack", replace the battery with a charged one or remove the battery, take it somewhere to charge it and return with it charged.

However I assume that time is a factor and leaving the car potentially unlocked doesn't appeal either.  Jump leads would be my number 1 option.

Of course if you are a member of a motoring organisation which provides a breakdown service, you could call them out.